# javascript find character in string from reverse

Tags: javascript, reactjs, search

I want specific search functionality on my website.

i.e:  In the search textbox user type

> uname:admin,age:30

so I need that type of javascript code when the user type **uname** and press enter key then ":" automatically add and type value "admin" and then press enter key again the "," automatically add. and so on...

please give me any hint for doing this

I am confused when I add ":" or ","

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Store last added character in variable. When enter key is pressed, change this variable to new value and add this char to your string.

Comment: but when user clean some input then ??

Comment: You wrote about pressing enter key, no cleaning input... Than you can check what chars are cleaned and if it's `:` or `,`, change variable value. Or you can count number of `:` and `,`, or millions other ways. A small hint, searching like `key:value,key:value` isn't good idea, try to think about that.

Comment: ok @pavel I'll try this way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understanded your Question correctly this should work:

```js
const input = document.getElementById('search')
input.addEventListener('keypress', e => {
  if (e.keyCode === 13) {
    e.preventDefault()
    const value = e.target.value
    if (!value) return
    if (value.match(/^(\w+:\w+,)*\w+$/)) {
      e.target.value = value + ':'
    } else if (value.match(/^(\w+:\w+,)*\w+:\w+$/)) {
      e.target.value = value + ','
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<input type="text" id="search">
```

Or if you want to clean input and store data:

```js
const input = document.getElementById('search')

let data = ''

input.addEventListener('keypress', e => {
  if (e.keyCode === 13) {
    e.preventDefault()
    const value = e.target.value
    if (!value) return
    if (!data || data.match(/^(\w+:\w+,)*$/)) {
      data += value + ':'
      e.target.value = ''
      console.log(data)
    } else if (data.match(/^(\w+:\w+,)*\w+:$/)) {
      data += value + ','
      e.target.value = ''
      console.log(data)
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<input type="text" id="search">
```